# Uploading files via trigger.io forge

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I'm using the Forge file module to try and upload an image from the gallery. Forge is running on Android 2.3 and the image selection capture bit works fine. But when I try to send the file with Request.Ajax() I get a forge exception.

I've dumped the output from the Catalyst log below

```
Request URL:forge.request.ajax
Request Method:undefined
Status Code:400 error

{ url: 'http://example.com/',
  username: null,
  password: null,
  data: null,
  headers: { Accept: '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' },
  timeout: 60000,
  type: 'POST',
  boundary: null,
  files: 
   [ { uri: 'content://media/external/images/media/212#Intent;end',
       name: 'Image',
       height: 500,
       width: 500 } ],
  fileUploadMethod: 'raw' }  // <- got this from a blog post,
```

And this is what I get in return

```
{ type: 'UNEXPECTED_FAILURE',
  message: 'Forge Java error: FileNotFoundException: http://example.com/' }
```

I've checked the server side and confirmed there is no problem there (Made a test script that posts there). The app posts to the server if I remove the file attach calls.

I've looked at the sample code posted here but it seems to be using the old API and I can't find some of the methods - https://github.com/trigger-corp/photo-log/blob/master/photolog.js

Am I doing anything wrong in the file call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no obvious problems with your Catalyst output: the `FileNotFoundException` just indicated something went wrong on the server side. In this case, I guess example.com wasn't expecting a multipart encoded POST.

We pushed some code live yesterday which makes our request.ajax error messages much clearer: I'd suggest you rebuild and re-run your app and see if you can tell what the server-side problem is.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be working now. Will put up more details if I get an inkling as to why it might have broken. Could be a server issue after all.